# Bootstrap modal box is disappearing in AEM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal, aem

This is my html code for bootstrap modal. Its working as expected in my local browser but when I am running in AEM, the modal box comes for a second and disappears. I read many answers on stackoveflow but none of them worked for AEM. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button type="button" id="modalButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="javascript: return false;" >
            Click me
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue, the  data-toggle was not working

Added the open function here:

```
<a type="button" id="modalButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#myModal"  onclick="showmodal ();" >
            Click me
        </a>
```

And the close function here:

```
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="hidemodal ()">&times;</button>

Added these two within the script tag


function showmodal () {
            $("#myModal").show();
        }
        function hidemodal () {
            $("#myModal").hide();
        }
```